# What causes IocLookupException?

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I wonder what causes `IocLookupException` in an adonis project. To be more specific, `E_IOC_LOOKUP_FAILED: Cannot resolve "..." namespace from the IoC Container`

What methods/tools can be used to determine the root of the issue so that you can prevent the exception?

Note: AdonisJS V4

Answer (score 1):

I faced this but for **V5** . the creator of Adonisjs in [this](https://github.com/adonisjs/core/discussions/1881) thread says it is caused by

> trying to access something from the container before the app is
> booted.